# How can I set left property to be equal to the content's width

Tags: html, css

I want a side panel to appear on the left side of my articles with all of the sharing buttons etc...

This is what I have right now, and it's not that bad but I don't want to hardcode a width because the content might change, so I want to add a `max-width`, and I would like to set the left to be equal to the content size.

I know I can do it with Javascript pretty easily but I was wondering if I didn't have to.

```html
<article>
  <div class="side-panel" ></div>
  ...content...
</article>
```

```
article{
   position: relative
}

.side-panel{
   position: absolute;
   width: 20%;
   left: 20%;
}
```

Edit: As per requested here's an example
[image]

Comment: could you share an an image of your desired layout?

Comment: looks like you could use flex-box model

Comment: What about changing max-width with @media queries. forget about using % on those kind of structures.

Comment: @YossiVainshtein I don't know but since I need to actually leave the current div I don't think it applies

Comment: Why would you want to set a left value on the sidepanel here to begin with - you _want_ it to be flush with the left side of the viewport, according to your image, no?

Comment: @CBroe yes and I want it to not scroll

Comment: What does scrolling have to do with this? If you put `left: 20%;` on the absolutely positioned sidebar, then it _won’t_ be flush with the left side of the viewport / positioning parent.

Comment: I think I might've misunderstood what you said, what I want is for the share article div to be side by side to the left article and I don't want to change the general layout of the whole website to accommodate for this

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)